# how to apply a text string in a variable with rename function

Tags: php, concatenation, rename

When using the PHP rename function I need to use text in a variable in the rename, but I can only get the rename to work when I manually enter the text, for example

If I use this

```
$original_file_name = '/my_file_path/Genesis _ Mad Man Moon _ A Trick Of The Tail (2007 Remaster) HQ Audio (128 kbps).mp3';
```

in rename like this

```
rename($filePath, $original_file_name);
```

it works

But if I do this

```
$a = "'";
$b = '/my_file_path/';
$c = $fin_name;
$original_file_name = $a.$b.$c.$a;
```

I get this

```
'/home2/ricstrav/domains/nerjabible.com/public_html/plupload_latest/Genesis _ Mad Man Moon _ A Trick Of The Tail (2007 Remaster) HQ Audio (128 kbps).mp3
```

'
with the end quote spaced two lines down from the end of the line so it does not rename.

Since I made this post, I have been thoroughly testing different options of rename, so far i have established the following

I am using this line of code to rename a file that has been uploaded to my server rename("{$filePath}.part", $original_name);

Where filePath is this file file_6278ea910fbf3 and the rename $original_name is the variable which contains the text ine below

Genesis _ Mad Man Moon _ A Trick Of The Tail (2007 Remaster) HQ Audio (128 kbps).mp3

when the rename fuction completes the file file_6278ea910fbf3 disappears off the directory on the server, but if I use this

rename("{$filePath}.part", "Genesis _ Mad Man Moon _ A Trick Of The Tail (2007 Remaster) HQ Audio (128 kbps).mp3");

It works perfectly

How can I make the variable $original_name reflect the same text, is there a 'normlising' option in php?

Comment: rename wont work if you to wrap the path in quotes (the `$a` var)

Comment: So what  should the syntax be for rename using your suggestion?

Comment: $original_file_name = "Genesis _ Mad Man Moon _ A Trick Of The Tail (2007 Remaster) HQ Audio (128 kbps).mp3";

rename($filePath, $original_file_name); 
works


$original_file_name = $fin_name; ($fin_name is the same text from implode array)

rename($filePath, $original_file_name); 

doesnt work, it deletes the file.

Comment: No need for using `$a`. Just do `$original_file_name = $b.$c; rename($filePath, $original_file_name);`.

Comment: It deletes the $filePath file in the directory

Comment: `rename()` does not delete any files.

Comment: Markus Zeller so where do the files go  are they hidden